# Calling server side function onclick of TD

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a asp `ImageButton` which has its corresponding `Onclick` event like `OnClick="imgSubscriberInformation_Click"`, this imagebutton is inside a `td`, so I want to call `imgSubscriberInformation_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)` on click of `td`, how can I do this? the `td` doesnot support serverside click event.

Also, I need the `imageURL` of `imagebutton` to be passed on every click.

aspx code:

aspx.cs code:

```
protected void imgSubscriberInformation_Click(object sender,ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  hidCtrl.Value = "false";
  if (hidSubscribeInfo.Value == "")
  {
      if (imgSubscriberInformation.ImageUrl == "Images/downarrow.png")
      {
        LoadUserControl();
        PopulateData();
        imgSubscriberInformation.ImageUrl = "Images/uparrow.png";
      }
  }
  else if (hidSubscribeInfo.Value != "")
  {
    imgSubscriberInformation.ImageUrl = "Images/uparrow.png";
    LoadUserControl();
    PopulateData();
    hidSubscribeInfo.Value = "";
  }     
}
```

Comment: can you paste code, so I can help you

Comment: look at runat="server"  but show code us your code for further enlightenment

Comment: <td><asp:ImageButton ID="imgSubscriberInformation" runat="server" ImageAlign="Right" ImageUrl="Images/downarrow.png"
                                                  CssClass="ImgMargin" OnClientClick="javascript:return SubscribeImageClick();" OnClick="imgSubscriberInformation_Click"/> </td>

Comment: apsx code is in the above comment.

Comment: you can use asp.net table instead of html table

Comment: can please paste code of html

Comment: @NareshPansuriya I have pasted in the comments above.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this entirely with jQuery/javascript. Grab all the TD's (or specify them by class) and assign to them an onclick event to trigger the click of the image button within.

```
//all TD's
$("#mytable td").on( "click", function() {
         $(this).find('img').trigger( "click" );
      });


//or
// by class
$(".tdWithImgButton").on( "click", function() {
         $(this).find('img').trigger( "click" );
      });
```

Comment: Also just changed .next to .find

Comment: You have really improved code. Although OP has not tagged question with jQuery but still a good solution

Comment: @EdPitt i tried the above code using class, but its not triggering the images click function. although $(this).find('img').length is 1.

Comment: Its calling the OnClientClick function, but i need to call OnClick function.

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found a solution,
i moved the onClient click function to TD
and inside the javascript function i did this "__doPostBack("imgSubscriberInformation", "");"
this will call the click event of the imageButton.
Thanks for your time.